# Could FB API send request to particular friend

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I know I can use FB Api to send the request, but I need to pick up those guys from my friend list. Is there a way, I can preselect the particular friends from the list or send the request directly to some particular guys?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).

Comment: I know. However, in that case I get entire friend list and I need to check it through to see who I wanna send the message. This is not what I want. Is there a way I can pre-select based on the particular user's objects, for example, comment or photo?